# Spring Global Method Security And Aspectj

Tags: java, spring, security, aspectj

I have finished the configuration of global-method-security which is using @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true),and now I need to apply aspectj-autoproxy(@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)) for some extra method like making a log.But I find these two are conflict with each other.I know the reason for their conflict, but I do not know how to solve it.All these configurations are java-based.Please tell me if you know the solution.Thank you very much!

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@ComponentScan
public class AspectConfig {

    @Bean
    public ActionRecord record()
    {
        return new ActionRecord();
    }
}  

WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
Jan 07, 2018 6:02:30  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you're getting?

Comment: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0;

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow,and I don't know how to paste more details about this...

Comment: You can edit your original post and put any related information there. The more there is the more we'll be able to help you!

Comment: I’ve edited, does these information useful?(thank you very much!)

Comment: The error seems to be stemming because of this: warning no match for this type name: beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName] ...can you paste this class as well?

Comment: I’ve pasted the controller code which throws the exception.And my project could be work well if I discard Aspectj's configuration file.

Comment: So my guess would be that you need to replace beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller with beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller.AuthorityController in your aspectj configuration file

Comment: OMG....I‘ve written the wrong path...Thank you very much.I've thought it for two days..Thank you very much!It's solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include all classes in your package, you need to specify the following in your AspectJ config file: `beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller.*`

Otherwise, you can just specify `beike.visitorsystem.authority.controller.AuthorityController`